# Tizen Package not found. Please build. Cannot start debugger

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, package, tizen

The error " **Tizen Package not found. Please build. Cannot start debugger.** " happens when trying to run your Tizen app in Visual Studio Xamarin. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

and the solution is to do the following steps: - To set up the NuGet package manager:

1- Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings.

2- NuGet package manager settings 
3- **Uncheck the Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio option.**

then Building the Project and Run. 
good luck.

Comment: Does not work. Still facing the same error for me. Could you elaborate?